# Elements to be cleared - Wall - Mootools

Tags: javascript, html, mootools

Wall elements/images get created but never destroyed. After a slideshow happens for a while, many images are loaded and slows down the slideshow  animation speed. There is a little lag/stutter when the wall moves.

It appends each wall tile as an element to the html as the slideshow keeps going. Not sure how to remove those elements dynamically:

```
<div class="tile" col="141" row="1" rel="141x1" style="position: absolute; left: 38775px; top: 275px; width: 275px; height: 275px;">
    <p class="profText" style="opacity: 1; visibility: visible;">
        @SoSp33chl3ss
    </p>
    <img class="social-logo" src="../assets/images/tile/tw-tile-logo.png" style="opacity: 1; visibility: visible;">
    <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Cr2OefhUMAAZMD5.jpg" class="prof" style="opacity: 1; visibility: visible;">
</div>
```

Any way to fix this?

[image: Wall Image]

UPDATE: Code for my wall:

```
var mediaWall = new Wall("myWall", {
    "draggable":true,
    "autoposition":true,
    "inertia":true,
    "width":275,
    "height":275,
    "slideshow":true,
    "transition":Fx.Transitions.Expo.easeInOut,
    "showDuration": 7000,
    callOnUpdate: function(items) {
        items.each(function (e, i) {
            var tw = mentions[counter];
            createAndInjectNode(mediaWall, counter, tw, e);
            counter++;
            if (counter >= mentions.length)
                counter = 0;
        });
        // FIXED: Include this code to avoid stopping of wall slideshow after drag
        mediaWall.clearSlideShow();
        mediaWall.initSlideshow();
    }
});
mediaWall.initWall();
```

Comment: Please add the js code/excerpt responsible for the slideshow.

Comment: @Bjoern I included the code but the wall plugin is responsible for the slideshow animation